# Stock status instock and out of stock filter in layered navigation aggregation graphql magento 2.4.6

Tags: graphql, aggregations, magento2.4.4-p2

How to add stock availability in layered navigation graphql

```
{
    products(filter: {category_id:{eq: "4"}}) {
        total_count
        aggregations{
            attribute_code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can check this file: /var/www/html/m246/vendor/magento/module-catalog-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/Products/Attributes/Collection.php Might be it helps you.